# theme_folder_url issue

Tags: add-on, add-on-development, config, config-overrides

Should be a quick one for the EE add-on devs out there.

Most add-ons do support having:

```
$config['path_third_themes']    = $base_path . "/assets/third_themes/";
$config['url_third_themes']     = $base_url . "/assets/third_themes/";
```

in the config file.

I've noticed that Field Editor and Redactee don't.

I popped open those add-ons to replace instances of theme_folder_url with url_third_themes but they still don't want to load the appropriate styling.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you copy/paste a code snippet?

Basically, what you have to do is search for theme_folder_url and replace it with url_third_themes - plus you also have to remember to drop the third_party on the path.

so:

```
$this->EE->config->item('theme_folder_url').'third_party/field_editor/css/field_editor.css
```

becomes:

```
$this->EE->config->item('url_third_themes').'field_editor/css/field_editor.css
```

I have to do it on a lot of add-ons, which is mildly annoying as it should be sorted by now.

Comment: so in the instances where I've changed that and still the add-on images are missing, what would be the issue?

Comment: I'd need to see some code examples to be honest Steve. The change as above *should* work, but if it isn't it might be somewhere else the reference is being called.

Comment: here's mcp.field_editor.php http://d.pr/n/otCI and here's field_row.php http://d.pr/n/lRH7 for that particular add-on

Comment: so your mcp.field_editor.php still has lots of references to theme_folder_url - you need to replace it as follows: $this->EE->cp->add_to_head('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$this->EE->config->item('url_third_themes').'field_editor/css/field_editor.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');

Comment: as Sheldon Cooper would say "Bazinga"

Answer (score 2):

According the Core.php EE library, the config needs to be:

```
$config['theme_folder_url']     = $base_url . "/assets/third_themes/";
```

But latest versions of EE add the new third_party themes var:

```
$config['url_third_themes']     = $base_url . "/assets/third_themes/";
```

But also keep in mind that EE will automatically append "third_party" to this. So for example the final URL will be "example.com/assets/third_themes/third_party/redactee/".

**Changing folder structure for 100% compatibility**

If you want to make things compatible for addons that do and dont support the new variable you can structure your assets folder to the following:

```
/assets/themes/third_party/redactee/
/assets/themes/third_party/field_editor/
```

And then set both the config vars to the following:

```
$config['theme_folder_url']     = $base_url . "/assets/themes/";
$config['url_third_themes']     = $base_url . "/assets/themes/third_party/";
```

This should ensure all addons work with the new third_party themes location, regardless of supporting the url_third_themes var.

**Note:**
This solution will involve moving the EE CP theme folders into the assets folder as well, but thats the price you pay to ensure 100% compatibility without editing 3rd party addons.

Comment: is that at odds with http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#url-third-themes then?

Comment: Just checked and it seems they've added the config var you describe in the latest versions of EE. I was looking at 2.5.2. 

There is a conditional that uses 'url_third_themes' if set, but if not it falls back to 'theme_folder_url' as I describe above.

Answer (score 2):

For Field Editor you can add this:

`$this->theme_url = defined('URL_THIRD_THEMES') ? URL_THIRD_THEMES . '/field_editor/' : $this->EE->config->item('theme_folder_url') . 'third_party/field_editor/';`

inside the `public function __construct()` method.

And then swap out the instances of:

`$this->EE->config->item('theme_folder_url')` and `$this->EE->config->slash_item('theme_folder_url')`

for

`$this->theme_url`

don't forget `protected $theme_url;` somewhere after the start of the class itself.

For example on line 238 of mcp.field_editor.php (v1.0.3) the following:

`$this->EE->cp->add_to_head('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$this->EE->config->item('theme_folder_url').'third_party/field_editor/css/field_editor.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');`

would be changed to:

`$this->EE->cp->add_to_head('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $this->theme_url . 'css/field_editor.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');`

Note: this is a bit rough and you'll have to work through each add-on accordingly though, probably something similar will need to happen for Redactee as well.